# Can I use sub Select in the place of DateTime Expression in MySQL's TIMESTAMPDIFF function?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to calculate total Seconds between start time and end time. And obviously `TIMESTAMPDIFF` in `MySQL` does the job pretty good with **DateTime** Expressions Like

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2018-10-30 04:45:42','2018-10-30 06:01:42');
```

But I want to do is to use Sub Selects replacing expressions.But I'm getting error.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                    (SELECT TIMESTAMP(start_time) 
                     FROM shift 
                     WHERE TIME(NOW()) >= start_time AND 
                     TIME(NOW()) <= end_time) AS start_time, NOW())
```

So all my question is, Is it possible to replace `DateTime` Expression in `TIMESTAMPDIFF` with Sub Selects? How can I achieve this?

**Update:** The sub select in TIMESTAMPDIFF is returning a scalar value i.e timestamp i.e **2018-10-30 06:00:00**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but the subqueries need to be *scalar* subqueries.  A scalar subquery returns one column and at most one row.  You can accomplish this using `limit 1` or an aggregation function (with no `group by`).

Presumably, you want a query like this:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMP(start_time), NOW())
from shift
where TIME(NOW()) >= start_time and TIME(NOW()) <= end_time;
```

EDIT:

If you have a scalar subquery, then:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                     (SELECT TIMESTAMP(start_time) 
                      FROM shift 
                      WHERE TIME(NOW()) >= start_time AND 
                            TIME(NOW()) <= end_time
                     ), NOW()
                    )
```

The `as start_time` doesn't belong.

Comment: Could you make the query more succinct by using `WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time`?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff But the second query is returning a scalar value I believe. Correct me if I'm wrong. And that scalar Subquery is what I want to use to replace first datetime expression in 1st query. Update has been made in the question

Comment: @fubar . . . yes.